# Why HTTP request with file upload fails on first request (only)?

Tags: go, file-upload, httphandler

I've got a problem with an HTTP handler.
When I start the HTTP server, **the first request** to this handler receiving an uploaded file raise an error:

`multipart: Part Read: read tcp 127.0.0.1:9002->127.0.0.1:37704: read: bad file descriptor`

**The next requests work perfectly.**

Here is the beginning of the Handler :

```
func FileNewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err!= nil {
    log.Fatal(err) // Here is where the error is logged
    return
  }

...
```

Just for information, I have Nginx as proxy, althought I don't think the problem comes from here.

Does anyone have an idea of the origin of the error?

Thank you for your help ;-)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of code to reproduce?

Comment: I'm trying to provide an example to reproduce the error but I can't...
The example works correctly where my handler in the full app fails.
I can't understand why.

Comment: I'm beginning to find the answer. I'm using goagain (https://github.com/rcrowley/goagain) to restart the server after a build. If I stop and start the server I don't have any problem, but if I restart using gogain the first upload after the restart fails. I continue to search deeper and I'll post a comment if I find the origin of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the last comment the problem comes from goagain.
I've found that there is an open issue which is not currently merged : https://github.com/rcrowley/goagain/issues/25